# MongoID atomic update on embeds_many fields

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, atomic

Using `rails4` and `mongoid` we have `embeds_many` relation of `MyEmbed` model for the `MyModel` I need to do atomic update so the `embed.status` of the latests inserted field will rewrite the old embed fields statuses. And of course I need it in atomic operation as it can bring inconstancies.

Example:

**my_embed.rb**

```
class MyEmbed
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  STATUS_ACTIVE = 1
  STATUS_INACTIVE = 3

  field :data,         type: String
  field :status,       type: Integer, default: STATUS_ACTIVE

  embedded_in :my_model
end
```

**my_model.rb**

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :my_models, order: :created_at.desc

  field :data,         type: String
end
```

And

```
mymodel = MyModel.new(data: 'data')
mymodel.save!

mymodel.my_embeds.create!(data: 'Dummy data')
```

Then on the next create of the embed field I want to atomically update the old status to inactive state.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I believe my_model.rb class name should be MyModel, and it embeds_many :my_embeds

Answer (score 0):

Embedded documents are essentially arrays with json within them, however you can still perform atomic updates on them. You can read about atomic updates here (https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-persistence/#atomic)

Therefore you can just do the following:

```
my_model = MyModel.create(data:'this is my model')
=> #<MyModel _id: 57175de579acba0f1ea0dd30, created_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:57 UTC, updated_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:57 UTC, data: "this is my model", _type: "MyModel">
my_model.my_embeds.create(data: 'this is my embed', status:'created')
=> #<MyEmbed _id: 56935de579acba0f1ea0dd30, created_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:59 UTC, updated_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:59 UTC, data: "this is my embed", status:'created', _type: "MyEmbed">
my_model.my_embeds.count
=> 1
my_model.data
=> 'this is my model'
my_model.my_embeds.first.data
=> 'this is my embed'
my_model.my_embeds.first.status
=> 'created' 
my_model.my_embeds.first.set(status:'updated')
=> #<MyEmbed _id: 56935de579acba0f1ea0dd30, created_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:59 UTC, updated_at: 2016-04-20 10:46:03 UTC, data: "this is my embed", status:'updated', _type: "MyEmbed">
my_model.my_embeds.first.status
=> 'updated'
```

Just a note on using 'first', in the latest mongo you need to put a sort in front of, such as .asc(:_id) as as of mongoid 5 there is no sort added to .first automatically.

**UPDATE:** As the question has been updated, so has the answer.

I am assuming that you went you state you was to atomically update, you are not referring to automatically (i.e. via a callback) on the embedding creation (https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-callbacks/).

Assuming this is true, you just want to do this:

```
my_model = MyModel.create(data:'this is my model')
=> #<MyModel _id: 57175de579acba0f1ea0dd30, created_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:57 UTC, updated_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:57 UTC, data: "this is my model", status:1, _type: "MyModel">
my_model.my_embeds.create(data: 'this is my embed')
=> #<MyEmbed _id: 56935de579acba0f1ea0dd30, created_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:59 UTC, updated_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:59 UTC, data: "this is my embed", _type: "MyEmbed">
my_model.my_embeds.count
=> 1
my_model.set(status:MyModel::STATUS_INACTIVE)
=> #<MyModel _id: 57175de579acba0f1ea0dd30, created_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:57 UTC, updated_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:59 UTC, data: "this is my model", status:3, _type: "MyModel">
```

**Answer to Comment:**

There are two possible answers to your question depending on which one you are asking. Are you asking about transactions & rollbacks or about atomically updating multiple fields. I believe you are asking about the simpler of the two which is just how do you atomically update multiple fields.

This is just passing in multiple fields like so:

```
my_model.set(status:MyModel::STATUS_INACTIVE, data:'atomically update this as well')
=> #<MyModel _id: 57175de579acba0f1ea0dd30, created_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:57 UTC, updated_at: 2016-04-20 10:45:59 UTC, data: "atomically update this as well", status:3, _type: "MyModel">
```

Comment: General Idea behind my question is how to update two or more embed fields in a document in atomic way. (In one transaction for SQL). So if one of the operations fails the overall operation will fallback to the initial state. I know about the `model.set` method, but how can I use it for 2 or more fields?

Comment: I see the update to the answer and it's still the same. We already know how set works, so how you will update attributes of 2 embed fields in a document at once (atomically) with `set` ?